# CakePHP 3 - pagination - how to sort calculated field?

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, calculated-columns, cakephp-3.x

Sorry for my English, but I hope You will understand me.

Field `availability` does not exist in the database. It was subsequently created in `formatResults`. The results are displayed correctly, **but it is not possible to sort by the `availability` field.**

I tried this way but it does not work:

```
$query = $this
    ->WebshopProducts
    ->find('all')
    ->
    ->formatResults(function($results) {
        return $results->map(function($row) {
            if($row->stock_total - $row->stock_min > 0){
                $row->availability='Yes';
            }else{
                $row->availability='No';
            }
            return $row;
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$this->paginate = [ 'sortWhitelist'=>['availability']];`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this
->WebshopProducts
->find('all')
->select('Availibility'=>'(WebshopProducts.stock_total - WebshopProducts.stock_min)', **(Other required fields)**)
->order('Availibility'=>"DESC")
->formatResults(function($results) {
    return $results->map(function($row) {
        if($row->stock_total - $row->stock_min > 0){
            $row->availability='Yes';
        }else{
            $row->availability='No';
        }
        return $row;
    });
});
```

In your view file it should be

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Availibility'); ?></th>
```

I am not sure but you can try this.

Comment: Thank you Haresh for good solution. I solved the problem in a different way.My solution is below

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. This may helps someone:

```
$query = $this->WebshopProducts->find('all');
            $availabilityCase = $query->newExpr()->addCase(
            [$query->newExpr()->add(['(stock_total - stock_min) >' => 0]),$query->newExpr()->add(['(stock_total - stock_min) <=' => 0])],['YES','NO'],['string','string']);
            $query->select(['id','active','title','price','stock_total','position','availability' => $availabilityCase]);        
        $this->set('webshopProducts', $this->paginate($query));
```